# How to define a good data structure for an entity in Python?

Tags: python, class

I want to dealing entities with python. Each entity has several Attribute-Value pairs and several types. For example, "iPhone" as an entity, it has AV pairs as:

```
Developer, Apple Inc
CPU, Samsung
Manufacturer, Foxconn
```

and it has types as:

```
smartphone
mobilephone
telephone
```

I wish to define `class` for the entity. However, I need to store the information of a 2-dimension vector, `attribute-value pair` and a `type`. But the code below does not work. So how can I define a good data structure for this kind of entity (perhaps without `class`)?

```
class entity:
def __init__(self, type, av[]):
    self.type=type
    self.av[]=av[]
```

Comment: Use a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) which is a class that writes itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your code - you don't need `[]` anywhere in your class.

Below is an example where you could use `list` for type information and `dict` for attributes:

```
class Entity:

   def __init__(self, types, attributes):
       self.types = types
       self.attributes = attributes

iphone = Entity(
    types=['smartphone', 'mobilephone', 'telephone'],
    attributes={
        'Developer': ['Apple Inc'],
        'CPU': ['Samsung'],
        'Manufacturer': ['Foxconn', 'Pegatron'],
    },
)
```

Comment: for type u can use `*args`

Comment: @matino , thanks for your answer. I have a further question that, I use `dict` for attributes. However, if `iphone` have more than 2 attributes such as `Manufacturer, Foxconn` and `Manufacturer, Pegatron`, then I use `dict[attribute]=value`, I can only get one item.

Comment: Well you can use `list` for the values and have as many as you like. I have modified my example.

Answer (score 3):

Your indentation is messed up:

```
class entity:
    def __init__(self, type, av[]):
        self.type=type
    self.av[]=av[]
```

Further; you should ideally create a class Entity and a subclass IPhone that inherits it. Every attribute should be a class attribute, and not just a value inside a list/dict. Something like this:

```
class Entity(object):
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type = type
    ... attributes and methods common to all entities

class IPhone(Entity):
    def __init__(self, developer, cpu, manufacturer):
        Entity.__init__(self, "smartphone")
        self.developer = developer
        self.cpu = cpu
        self.manufacturer = manufacturer
```